# Mouse Tracking In Qt6

Tags: qt, mouseevent

I want to make a program that can track mouse movement, but also be able to click some pushbuttons and enter some text in line edit, but when override `mouseMoveEvent` in `MainWindow` and `setMouseTracking(true)` in constructor , it can't track the mouse over the pushbuttons.

I saw this could be done using QApplication::notify(QObject* obj, QEvent* ev), but I don't know where and how to implement it.

Comment: The mouse move events are, generally speaking, sent to whichever widget the mouse is over: that might not be the `QMainWindow` itself but, instead, one of its child widgets.  Other than that, I'm really not sure what you're trying to do without you showing some code.